# Playing multiple wav files with SoundPlayer() without the sounds overlapping

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, media, wav

I am trying to play a .wav file with `SoundPlayer()`, and then use `SpeechSynthesizer()` to say a sentence afterwards.

The problem is that `SoundPlayer()` plays on a new thread, so my program talks while the .wav file is playing.  I need it to start speaking after the .wav file has finished.

my example code:

```
SoundPlayer sound = new SoundPlayer("drum_roll.wav");
sound.Play();

SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
synth.Volume = 100;
synth.Speak("Hello World");
```

Is there a way to stop `SoundPlayer()` from starting on a new thread, if not how can I achieve the desired result?

P.S. I'm quite new to C# and it is my first time posting a C# related question so any feedback on my code/question (especially the way I tagged this question) is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can afford stopping your main thread, you can use

```
SoundPlayer.PlaySync()
```

that loads and plays the .wave file on the calling thread.

[.NET SoundPlayer.PlaySync() documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.media.soundplayer.playsync?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: So dreadfully simple.  That was exactly what I was after thank you.